# string subscript out of range error

Tags: c++, string

Hey I have problem with this code. I have read some questions about it but i can't find problem in my code. Help me if you can guys.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "You have 20 attempts";
    string slowo="program";
    char litera;
    unsigned j=0;

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        if (j > slowo.size())j=0;

        litera = _getch();
        for(unsigned z=0;z < slowo.size();z++)
        {
            if (litera==slowo[j])
            {
                cout << slowo[j];
                break;
            }
            else cout << "-";
        }
        //cout << litera;

            j++;
    }getch();
}
```

I forgot about that little thing with string when i don't have an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading an index `slowo.size()` in `slowo`, but subscripting it 0-based, so `slowo` can only be indexed from `0` to `slowo.size()-1`. You need to change your condition to

```
if (j >= slowo.size())j=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

When string has length 4 it means there are characters on indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, i.e. `size() - 1`. Thus:

```
if (j > slowo.size()) j=0;
```

should be:

```
if (j >= slowo.size()) j=0;
```